# Update polyline when user is out of existing polyline google map

Tags: android

I am implementing google map for draw a route between two locations in Android app. Route is showing, but I am not able to update route when user goes out of route during ride (runtime).
**Q. How do i check if user goes out of route and how to update route on google map without refreshing map. Please help.**

Thanks,
Nisha

Comment: having same problem, please guide anyone

Answer (score 0):

->You can update the polyline without restarting/refreshing the map using the polyline.setPoints(new points); method.

->Check my answer here on how to dynamically update the points of polyline.

[update polyline according to the user moving android googleMaps v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038258/update-polyline-according-to-the-user-moving-android-googlemaps-v2/51131607#51131607)