# Delete polyline behind Current Location Marker Like Uber android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-location, google-polyline

In my application  i have a tracking option like Uber ,here i draw polyline
    from point A to point B, and i track current location  Here i want to delete 
    polyline line from poit A to current location dynamically  Like UBER 
    Application. how can i achive this ,give any suggestions

```
private List<Polyline> polylines = new ArrayList<Polyline>();


      @Override
public void onRoutingSuccess(ArrayList<Route> route, int i) {

    if (polylines.size() > 0) {
        for (Polyline poly : polylines) {
            poly.remove();
        }
    }


     polylines = new ArrayList<>();

    //add route(s) to the map.
    //In case of more than 5 alternative routes
    PolylineOptions polyOptions = new PolylineOptions();
    polyOptions.color(getResources().getColor(R.color.btn_green_color));
    polyOptions.width(7 + i * 3);
    polyOptions.addAll(route.get(0).getPoints());
    Polyline polyline = googleMap.addPolyline(polyOptions);
    polylines.add(polyline);

        if (curentDriverMarker != null) {
            curentDriverMarker.remove();
        }
        if (!base64.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            curentDriverMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(carPoint)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp)));

        } else {
            curentDriverMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(carPoint)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.point)));
        }



}
```

i want update polyline like this picture

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdI5H.png

Comment: have you solved @yuvraj

Comment: i have solved @M.Yogeshwaran

Comment: please share how you solved am struggling with this bro

Comment: bro share the logic how you solved this

Comment: sure bro @M.Yogeshwaran

Comment: refer my answer by usng this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038258/update-polyline-according-to-the-user-moving-android-googlemaps-v2/52276198#52276198

Comment: if uou have any doubt ask me

Comment: thanks bro il check and let you know

Comment: did you check that my solution @M.Yogeshwaran

Comment: have to check it bro