# Java android google maps change color polyline where I was

Tags: java, android, google-maps

This is how I draw a polyline :

```
 List<LatLng> latLngsList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (LegsItem leg : response.body().getRoutes().get(0).getLegs()) {
                for (StepsItem step : leg.getSteps()) {
                    List<LatLng> latLngs = PolyUtil.decode(step.getGeometry());
                    step.setLatLngs(latLngs);
                    latLngsList.addAll(latLngs);
                }
            }

            Polyline polyline1 = googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                    .addAll(latLngsList));
```

I draw this on color black but when I am on the polyline(In LatLtg), I want to change the color to blue. To detect if I am on the point, I use the below:

```
mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener
```

and check if the first not done point is near than 2 m :

```
double dis = currentLocation.distanceTo(location);
```

But it does not work correctly

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function distanceBetween which Computes the approximate distance in meters between two locations, and optionally the initial and final bearings of the shortest path between them.

```
public static boolean checkDistance(LatLng oldPosition, LatLng newPosition) {
        float[] results = new float[1];
        Location.distanceBetween(oldPosition.latitude, oldPosition.longitude,
                newPosition.latitude, newPosition.longitude, results);
        return results[0] <= 50.0;
    }
```

Here i set minimum distance 50 meter. these will return true if your current location(latlon) is within 50 miters from your polyline latlon.

Answer (score 0):

Define color value in `colors.xml`

**colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="blue">#0000EE</color>
</resources>
```

and set color like this :-

```
Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                .addAll(list)
                .color(R.color.blue));
```

**EDIT**

```
mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {

                for (LatLng nLatLng : latLngsList) {

                    double latitude = nLatLng.latitude;
                    double longitude = nLatLng.longitude;
                    double myLat = location.getLatitude();
                    double myLong = location.getLongitude();
                    
                    if (latitude == myLat && longitude == myLong) {


                        Polyline polyline1 = googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                                .add(nLatLng)
                                .color(R.color.blue));
                    } /*else {
                        Polyline polyline1 = googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                                .add(nLatLng)
                                .color(R.color.black));
                    }*/
                }


            }
        });
```

See also: [update-polyline-according-to-the-user-moving-android-googlemaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038258/update-polyline-according-to-the-user-moving-android-googlemaps-v2)